# Do I need a comma after "when" in this example?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> I do not know if anything is getting created when the contract gets uploaded.

Does this sentence warrant a comma after "when"?

Comment: If you put the clause "when the contract gets uploaded" at the beginning of the sentence, then you would put a comma after the clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

A comma is typically used to separate sub-clauses or items in a list. It is definitely not used after the word "when" in a situation like this.